# Water pump cycles at random times about once a day

Tags: water

- The pump brings water from an outside, below ground cistern into a house.
- The system as a whole performs normally.
- We have checked repeatedly for dripping taps and leaks.
- The pump can cycle during the evening or in the night when no-one is drawing water for any purpose.
- The pump does not run long, we estimate from half a minute to a minute.

This often wakes my wife which is bad enough. Is it a sign of impending doom?

Comment: Have you considered the check valve that prevents backflow to the cistern might be where the leak is?  Pressure is evidently going somewhere. I’ve seen a stethoscope used for a quick check.

Comment: @Tyson: No, that would not have occurred to me. Thanks. I will try to check it. Mind you I don't have a stethoscope.

Comment: It does sound like the backflow checkvalve (or foot valve in the cistern) to me. If you have a pressure gauge near the pump/pressure tank you can diagnose this by shutting off the main valve to the house and watching it -- if it goes down, water is leaving the tank from somewhere, and absent a visible leak it pretty much has to be the check valve.